# Java Finding Set Bits of Long

Tags: java

I have a long number. Now what I want is following (given in pseudo code) ,

```
for each two bits of that long

if the two bits == 11

then count++

(for example if number is "11 01 10 00 11" it will give count = 2)
```

Can anybody help me how to do this efficiently in Java ?

Comment: What should the answer be for 000011100000 ?

Comment: You tested the code of the accepted answer and it gives you 1 for 
0000001110000 ?

Comment: @Thorn, yes. My tested code here
long n = Long.valueOf("0000001110000",2);
  int cnt = 0;
  while (n != 0) {
    if ((n & 3) == 3) cnt++;
    n >>>= 2;
  }
System.out.print(cnt);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int count11(long n) {
  int cnt = 0;
  while (n != 0) {
    if ((n & 3) == 3) cnt++;
    n >>>= 2;
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

The even more efficient variant:

```
public static int count11(long n) {
  int cnt = 0;
  while (n != 0) {
    switch ((int)(n & 0x3F)) {
    case 0x3F: cnt += 3; break;
    case 0x3C: case 0x33: case 0xF: cnt += 2; break;
    case 0x30: case 0xC: case 3: cnt++;
    }
    n >>>= 6;
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Efficiency could be even greater if you shift by four bits and check two lowermost bit pairs in a switch -- or do it even with 8 bits. But I doubt you need it to be that efficient.